# Test what cgroup version a Docker container is running with

Tags: docker, containers, cgroups

The title almost says it all:

From within a running docker container, how can I find out if it is running with cgroups 1.0 or with cgroups 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

run the cmd

```bash
docker info | grep 'Cgroup Version'
```

it will print the cgroup version use by docker on your host

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question of 'within the container' but it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check whether cgroup2 is available or not with the command:

```
grep -c cgroup2 /proc/filesystems
```

If `1` is returned the cgroups 2.0 are available, but I'm not sure this will be sufficient to conclude that they are also used.

Comment: No, this is not sufficient unfortunately: It only shows that cgroup2 is available, not that Docker uses it. Taking Debian Buster as an example (where Docker still uses cgroup V1.0 by default), /proc/filesystems _does_ contain the line "nodev   cgroup2" nevertheless.